# Jquery place holder

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-validate

This looks very simple, but I can't figure it out. I'm using the jquery validate plugin. I validate all the files but what I want is to show the validation message alerts in the input text lines(for each field diffren alert),(for exapmle in the email input- "please fill email address" (if the mail wasn't filled) 
right now it appears under the all fields. 
How can I  use the jquery to update the placeholder, I know I should use write something like this but I don't know how to combine this in the code:

```
$(this).attr("placeholder", "please fill email address");
```

**In my html:**

```
<form method="post" action="#" class="xone-contact">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">                                 
            <div class=" margin-b-20">
                <input type="text" name="name"  class="form-control" placeholder="Full Name...." />
            </div>
            <div class=" margin-b-20">
                <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address...." />
            </div>     
            <div class=" margin-b-20">
                <input type="text" name="phone" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone Number..." />
            </div>    
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <textarea name="message" class="form-control margin-b-20" rows="5" placeholder="Message...."></textarea>        
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
                    <div class="data-status"></div> 
                </div>
            </div>     
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**In PHP :**

```
if (isset($_POST['action'])) { // Checking for submit form

$my_email = 'wow123@gmail.com'; // Change with your email address

if ($_POST['action'] == 'add') {
    $name       = trim(strip_tags(addslashes($_POST['name'])));
    $email      = trim(strip_tags(addslashes($_POST['email'])));
    $message    = trim(strip_tags(addslashes($_POST['message'])));
    $phone       = trim(strip_tags(addslashes($_POST['phone'])));
    $pattern_name   = '/^[a-zA-Z]{2}/';
    $pattern_email  = '/^[^\W][a-zA-Z0-9_]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)*\@[a-zA-Z0-9_]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)*\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/';
    $pattern_message   = '/^[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}/';
    $pattern_phone = '/^([0-9]{9,10})/';

    if ($email != '' && $message != '' && $phone != ''&& $name != '') {
        if (preg_match($pattern_email, $email)&& preg_match($pattern_name, $name)&& preg_match($pattern_message, $message)&& preg_match($pattern_phone, $phone) ) {
            $headers = 'From: ' . $email . "\r\n";
            $subject = 'Message from ' . $name;
            $message_phone= $message.'Phone number: '.$phone;
            mail($my_email, $subject, $message_phone,  $headers);

                    echo 'success|<div class="alert alert-success"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"><i class="ion-close"></i></button>Thank you! We will contact you shortly.</div>';

                    }
           elseif(!preg_match($pattern_email, $email)) {
            echo 'error|<div class="alert alert-danger"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"><i class="ion-close"></i></button>Please enter a valid email address.</div>';
        }
                     elseif(!preg_match($pattern_name, $name)) {
            echo 'error|<div class="alert alert-danger"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"><i class="ion-close"></i></button>Name must be more then 2 letters.</div>';

        }
                     elseif(!preg_match($pattern_phone, $phone)) {
            echo 'error|<div class="alert alert-danger"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"><i class="ion-close"></i></button>Phone must be 9-10 digits.</div>';

        }
                     elseif(!preg_match($pattern_message, $message)) {
            echo 'error|<div class="alert alert-danger"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"><i class="ion-close"></i></button>Message must be more than 2 letters.</div>';

        }
    } elseif ($name== ''&& $message != '' && $phone != '' && $email != '') {
        echo 'error|<div class="alert alert-danger"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"><i class="ion-close"></i></button>Please fill name</div>';
    }
            elseif ($phone== ''&& $message != '' && $name != '' && $email != '') {
        echo 'error|<div class="alert alert-danger"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"><i class="ion-close"></i></button>Please fill Phone number</div>';
    }
            elseif ($message== '' && $phone != ''&& $name != '' && $email != '') {
        echo 'error|<div class="alert alert-danger"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"><i class="ion-close"></i></button>Please fill Massage</div>';
    }
             elseif ($email== ''&& $message != '' && $phone != ''&& $name != '') {
        echo 'error|<div class="alert alert-danger"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"><i class="ion-close"></i></button>Please fill Email address</div>';
    }
            else{
                echo 'error|<div class="alert alert-danger"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"><i class="ion-close"></i></button>Please fill all the fields</div>';
            }
}

} else { // Submit form false
header('Location: index.html'); 
  }
 ?>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$('.xone-contact').submit(function() {
    var $form       = $(this);
    var submitData  = $form.serialize();
            var $phone      = $form.find('input[name="phone"]');
    var $email      = $form.find('input[name="email"]');
    var $name       = $form.find('input[name="name"]');
    var $message    = $form.find('textarea[name="message"]');
    var $submit     = $form.find('input[name="submit"]');
    var $dataStatus = $form.find('.data-status');

    $email.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            $phone.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $name.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $message.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $submit.attr('disabled', 'disabled');

    $dataStatus.show().html('<div class="alert alert-info"><strong>Loading...</strong></div>');

    $.ajax({ // Send an offer process with AJAX
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'assets/contact_form/process-contact.php',
        data: submitData + '&action=add',
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(msg){
            if (parseInt(msg, 0) !== 0) {
                var msg_split = msg.split('|');
                if (msg_split[0] === 'success') {                     
                    $phone.val('').removeAttr('disabled');
                    $email.val('').removeAttr('disabled');
                    $name.val('').removeAttr('disabled');
                    $message.val('').removeAttr('disabled');
                    $submit.removeAttr('disabled');
                    $dataStatus.html(msg_split[1]).fadeIn();
                } else {                 
                    $phone.removeAttr('disabled');
                    $email.removeAttr('disabled');
                    $name.removeAttr('disabled');
                    $message.removeAttr('disabled');
                    $submit.removeAttr('disabled');
                    $dataStatus.html(msg_split[1]).fadeIn();
                }
            }
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

Comment: If you are showing us some PHP, why not tag it with php? Or if the question isn't about PHP, why show us your PHP in the first place?

Comment: Please do not post duplicates.